# What is the remainder when 72^73^74 is divided by 10?

Tags: elementary-number-theory

Apart from using the cyclicity method, can we use the Binomial theorem and solve this?

Comment: What is a^b^c? $(a^b)^c$ or $a^{b^c}$?

Comment: Yeah... you need to specify $72^{73^{74}}$ or $(72^{73})^{74}$, that would be great.

Comment: It is standard that $\large a^{b^c}= \large a^{(b^c)}$

Comment: @Peter ? You mean it is standard that a^b^c $=a^{b^c}$ (because that a^{b^c}=a^(b^c) is twice the same formula with different types of brackets ...)??

Comment: If there are no brackets, $b^c$ has to be computed first.

Comment: @Peter: Not at all; the most common rule is left-to-right evaluation. For example, in Excel formulae or the Basic programming language (used in both Microsoft Office and Open Office) `a^b^c` is interpreted as `(a^b)^c`.

Answer (score 2):

New fixed answer:

$72 \equiv 2 $ (mod $5$), and the value of $2^k $ (mod $5$) depends on $k$ (mod 4) by Fermat's Little Theorem.

$73^{74} \equiv 1^{74} \equiv 1$ (mod 4).

So $72^{73^{74}} \equiv  2^{1 + 4k} \equiv 2$ (mod $5$)

But $72^{73^{74}}$ is clearly even, so applying the Chinese remainder theorem to $x \equiv 0$ (mod $2$) and $x \equiv 2$ (mod $5$), we obtain $x \equiv 2$ (mod $10$)

Comment: You apply [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) here, right? Why is this also valid when $a$ and $n$ are not coprime, as $72$ and $10$ are not?

Comment: This should now work :). Thanks for spotting that!

Answer (score 1):

$73^{74} = 1\mod(4)$ , so $72^{73^{74}}=2\mod(10)$

Comment: $2^4 \equiv 6 $ (mod 10)

Comment: Same question here. You apply [Euler's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem) here, right? Why is this also valid when $a$ and $n$ are not coprime, as $72$ and $10$ are not?

Comment: Don't need to apply any theorem. Look at the last digit of 2^k: Starting with k = 0, the last digit of 2^k is 1, 2, 4, 8, 6, 2, 4, 8, 6 and so on. It's obvious that the digit must repeat. So the last digit of 2^k is 2, 4, 8 or 6 if k = 1, 2, 3 or 0 modulo 4, with the exception that the last digit of 2^0 is 1.

Comment: @gnasher729 :) What are you saying?? My comment was referring to Peter's answer, not to the undoubted fact that $2^4\equiv 6\pmod{10}$.